# Code technique - jquery login with php server

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, intel-xdk

It is my 2nd day developing mobile app. And for now I'm dealing with login credentials.

I'm using Intel XDK. I have an idea/logic on how the login page will work. But at some point, I'm new to jquery ajax method. What I would like to accomplish is how to successfully implement it with existing server(website).

This is the submit button code.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#login", function(evt)
{
    var email=$("#input_email").val();
    var password=$("#input_password").val();
    var user_data = 'email='+email+'&password='+password;

    if($.trim(email).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "www.mysite.com/app/login_user.php",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: user_data,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $(#loader).css({display: "block" });
            },
            success : function(data){
                $(#loader).css({display: "none"});
                alert(data);},
            error : function(httpReq,status,exception){
                alert(status+" "+exception);
            }
        });
    }
     return false;
});
```

And This is my code on php server-side.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //newly added
include('../config.php');

session_start();

if(isset($_GET['email']) && isset($_GET['password'])){

        $get = $_GET;
        array_walk_recursive($get, 'clean');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE //some condition here ";
    $user = db::select_row($sql);
    $access = 'true password';//should logged in the user, and landed to home page.


    if($user['user_status'] == 'active' || $user['user_status'] == 'new' || $user['user_status'] == 'not active'){
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user['user_email'];
            $_SESSION['user_fullname'] = $user['user_fullname'];

    }elseif($user){
            $access = 'Account is deactivated!'; //Show as popup message
    }else{
            $access = 'Username and password didn\'t match.'; //Show as popup message
    }

echo json_encode($access); //newly added
}   
////////Conditional code to be added here base on $access value.
////////Send result to mobile app and respond.
////////Need some help. 

?>
```

I hope you understand my needs. All ideas for improvement is greatly appreciated.

**Edited#1**: I added some line of code to my php server and some additional code to my jquery code. It is working now, it is alerting the data $access.

Question#1: How can I use the server response(e.g "$access value" is = 'true password' or 'Username and password didn't match.') to make some action on the client-side?

Comment: My error at the moment is this: parsererror ERROR: jQuery22304022783309711156_1464053945461 was not called

Comment: you are making a jsonp request but not returning jsonp from server

Comment: @charlietfl yes, that was i'm missing.

Comment: I don't know what is the proper approach for that.

Comment: $.ajax({ type : "POST", ... and by php $_POST

Comment: @MilosLulic have tried that but same error.

Comment: @c.k but you dont use this "SELECT * FROM user WHERE //some condition here"  as your sql query?

Comment: @MilosLulic Yes, I don't use it in my actual code. my condition there is this. SELECT * FROM user WHERE TRIM(user_email) = '{$post['email']}' AND (TRIM(user_password) = md5('{$post['password']}'))";